# Notification from website with webscraping and telegram bot

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, telegram-bot

I want to create a telegram bot that sends a message after a webscraping of a web-site with login (python - selenium). When the elements inside the website are updated the notification must appear in telegram (made by bot).
Are there any links about it or further information?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Telegram bot server to establish full duplex connections between clients and Telegram accounts through WebSocket protocol.
This bot is been created to interact with react-telegram-chatbox, but can also be used with custom applications. here is the link https://github.com/jonamat/telegram-socket-bot

Comment: The web site is not mine, is a pubblic web site